# Unable to create valid SPDataSource Select Command

Tags: data-view-web-part, filter, xslt-list-view-web-part

I am to use SharePoint Designer, no custom c# code.

I am currently using a SharePoint:SPDataSource on a DVWP to show a list. When the SelectCommand is blank, it works fine but I will need to create dynamic filter.

Working Data Source:

```
 <SharePoint:SPDataSource runat="server" DataSourceMode="List" SelectCommand="" UseInternalName="True" UseServerDataFormat="True" ID="spdatasource2">
```

I have a choice field, myField which is either 'Public' or 'Private', currently I am only looking to find items with 'Public'. I have tried:

```
 SelectCommand="<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='myField'/><Value Type='Text'>Public</Value></Eq></Where></Query></View>"
```

Errors: One or more field types are not installed properly

Also

```
 Selectcommand="&lt;View&gt;&lt;Query&gt;&lt;Where&gt;&lt;Eq&gt;&lt;FieldRef Name=&quot;myField&quot;/&gt;&lt;Value Type=&quot;Text&quot;&gt;Public&lt;/Value&gt;&lt;/Eq&gt;&lt;/Where&gt;&lt;/Query&gt;&lt;/View&gt;"
```

Errors: Cannot Complete this action

---

Eventually I am looking to build an equivalent of

```
 SelectCommand  = "Select * From myList Where myField like '"+@selectParam1+"'"
  <SelectParameter ID='selectParam1' DefaultValue="*" Location="QueryString"/>
```

I have also tried to use ajax on the address:

```
/vit_bin/owssvr.dll?Cmd=Display&List={guid}&View={guid}&XMLDATA=True&Query=*
```

This always downloads a file of the default view instead of show xml causing the POST request to fail.

Another attempt was to use xsltListViewWebPart but I could not get a valid query in that either.

Advice?

Answer (score 1):

Change `<Value Type='Text'>` to `<Value Type='Choice'>` in the `SelectCommand` CAML query

See [MSDN - SPFieldType Enumeration](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.sharepoint.spfieldtype%28v=office.14%29.aspx) for the different values you can use for each field type.

Comment: Can you explain why this should work? Since we don't even know the field type of the custom field

Comment: @Robert the op has stated "I have a choice field, myField which is either 'Public' or 'Private'"

Comment: True, I missed that, sorry! But I still see no good cause to use Choice instead of Text as Value Type, do you have a good source for that statement?

Comment: @Robert quiet right I should have provided that! I've updated my answer to include a reference for the different values.

Comment: Great, but these are FieldTypes, not the value types that SharePoint actually stores. Have you tried your solution? (Asking out of curiosity, since I find this interesting)

Comment: Yes that's true but the field type is equivalent to the value type in the CAML. I have used this before (although not in a SP Designer data source but I see no reason for the CAML to be different) also if you want to verify this you can use one of the CAML generation tools (I use CamlDesigner from http://www.camldesigner.com/) and it will generate the same code for choice fields.